# How do you swap a stylesheet in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, unique, stylesheet

First I've read through several questions about applying page specific stylesheets. My issue is that I have a few pages that need unique stylesheets only. The header contains the stylesheet used for most pages, so I need to swap that for the unique ones on those pages.

Wonder what I did wrong with this:

```
 <?php if ( is_page('unique_page') ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/unique_stylesheet.css' );//page-specific css for unique page
           }
       else {wp_enqueue_style( '<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>' ); //default stylesheet

 } ?>
```

Pages are blank when reloading them with this code in header.php.
If that's not the right method, what else would be? Again I don't want to load the default css for the unique pages, only the page specific stylesheets.

Comment: You have nested `<?php ?>` tags. Try getting rid of them.

Comment: Oh, it's obvious, yet I somehow missed it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I tried it. I don't need php tags inside the functions.php correct? So I tried (relevant code part only) wp_enqueue_style("bloginfo('template_url')/unique_stylesheet.css");, and got "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'template_url' (T_STRING)".

Comment: You should be using exactly what @Bass posted.

Comment: mevius, I was scattered brained, sry I should've seen that, thanks.

Comment: Ok so figured out the end of file error, but now I get this: "Call to undefined function add_action()". I put add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customstyles' ); after defining the customstyles function, if it helps.

Comment: make sure your code is in the functions.php file of your current theme

Comment: Thanks. The error is gone but the code somehow isn't working, as in, the default stylesheet is printed but not the unique as per the php conditional. Tried with add_action() both before and after the customstyles() declaration, btw, if it makes a difference, and passed the unique page's id to the is_page, still, so far only the default stylesheet loads so clearly the if statement is being ignored, but there's no error message pointing to it. I added it to the theme's functions.php.

Comment: Update, looked up in the codex and changed to the wp_eneueue_scripts( 'stylesheet_name', get_stylesheet_uri()) syntax, now the style is output as a style html tag, but still only the default style, not sure at this point, but the name for the unique style sheet is absolutely correct, and is printed under "Styles" in the theme editor yet isn't being applied.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customstyles' );` in your theme's functions.php with:

```
function customstyles() {
 if ( is_page('unique_page') ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( bloginfo('template_url').'/unique_stylesheet.css' );//page-specific css for unique page
           }
       else {wp_enqueue_style( bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ); //default stylesheet

}
```

Comment: Interesting. Will check it out.

Comment: you should the function.php in your theme folder, wp-contents/themes/{yourtheme}/function.php

Comment: Didn't see your second comments before adding 2nd comment, used the theme editor's functions php first time, thanks for that one.